What is the relation between two abelian varieties that have the same formal group?
Consider two abelian varieties $A$ and $B$ over the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ be the associated formal groups of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Assume that $\hat{A}=\hat{B}$.
Or, upon choice of coordinates, one gets two formal group laws $\hat{A}(X,Y)$ and $\hat{B}(X,Y)$ of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Then assume $\hat{A}(X,Y)=\hat{B}(X,Y)$.

What can we say about the relationship between $A$ and $B$?
Can we get an isogeny between $A$ and $B$ in some situations along with the above assumption?


My intuition says:
Since $A$ and $B$ have the same formal group, we expect they have at least similar local properties near identities because formal groups capture the local properties of their abelian varieties. At least $A$ and $b$ have the same dimension. Also, the corresponding $p$-divisible groups of $A$ and $B$ should intersect at a dense subset, that is, the corresponding $p$-power torsion point sets $A[p^{\infty}]$ and $B[p^{\infty}]$ have similar algebraic structures. It is possible to get a homomorphism between $A[p^{\infty}]$ and $B[p^{\infty}]$. Thus, it may turn out that $A$ and $B$ are isogenous.
Since $\hat{A}(X,Y)=\hat{B}(X,Y)$, it is obvious that $\text{dim}(A)=\text{dim}(B)$. To show $A$ and $B$ are isogenous, we need to find a homomorphism $\alpha: A \to B$ such that $\text{ker}(\alpha)$ is finite, see Proposition 6.1 in page 30. Consider the $p$-endomorphisms $[p]_{\hat{A}}$ and $[p]_{\hat{B}}$; both are equal. These $p$-endomorphisms have a fixed formal power series expression. Assume that $\text{ker}([p]_{\hat{A}})$ is finite, then $[p]_{\hat{A}}$ can be extended to the $p$-endomorphism $[p]_A: A \to B$, which also should have a finite kernel; otherwise, $\text{ker}([p]_{\hat{A}}$ may not be finite as the $p$-power torsion points set is dense in the ambient space.
If it was a characteristic $p$ field, then one could have used the Dieudonné modules to classify abelian varieties up to isogeny, I think. In that case, since the corresponding formal groups of $A$ and $B$ are equal, the Dieudonné modules are the same, so I think $A$ and $B$ should be in isogeny class.
I hope I will get some comments or answers to help my understanding.
Edit: I should clarify my question. As rightly pointed out by @Daniel Litt and @Wojowu in the comment section, I am indeed considering my abelian varieties $A$ and $B$ are integral models over the $p$-adic integer ring. For example, $A$ and $B$ are Néron models over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Do you really mean to consider formal groups over the p-adic field, rather than those of an integral model?

If two elliptic curves have the same formal group law for respective Weierstrass equations, then not only the curves are equal, but even the equations are equal as $F(X,Y) = X + Y -a_1, XY -a_2, X^2 Y -a_2, XY^2 -2a_3, X^3Y + \cdots + (-2a_1a_3 - 2a_4)X^4Y + \cdots + (-2a_1^3a_3 - 2a_1^2a_4 - 4a_1a_2a_3 - 2a_2a_4 - 2a_3^2 - 3a_6)X^6Y +\cdots$. For any ring of characteristic zero or coprime to $6$.

Strictly speaking, the first sentence doesn't make sense - the two formal groups won't be literally equal, I suppose you mean that they are isomorphic. This implies that for some choice of coordinates the corresponding formal group laws will be equal. However, over a field of characteristic zero, any two commutative formal group laws are isomorphic. As Daniel Litt suggests, you probably want to work integrally instead.

@DanielLitt, You are right. Indeed, I had in mind those abelian varities that are integral models (e.g., N$\acute{e}$eron model) over the $p$-adic integer ring so that the corresponding formal groups (laws) have integral coefficients.

Thanks for the clarification. And are you asking about equality of formal groups (arguably a bad notion, unless you e.g. fix Weierstrass models, as Chris Wuthrich does), or isomorphism?

@DanielLitt, for some choice of coordinates, the  corresponding formal group laws are same or coincide. This is my assumption.

@DanielLitt, For an elliptic curve, it is easier to fix a model by a certain equation; however, I am not sure how I would fix two integral models for any higher-dimensional abelian varieties. I would love to see it.

@ChrisWuthrich, can you tell me the reference of the example you mentioned?
